# Check input Content

Tags: python

i want the bot to Look if "Hello", "hello" or "Hi" is in the input content. I already tried with

```
hello = ["Hello", "hello", "Hi"]
msg = input()
if hello in msg:
```

and

```
hello = ["Hello", "hello", "Hi"]
msg = input()
if hello in str(msg):
```

Comment: ```if 'hello' in msg:``` Without quotes, it is considering ```hello``` as a variable and trying to fetch its value. If it is not defined then python crashes

Comment: What happened differently than what you expected when you tried those? Any errors?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write, hello is a list means
hello = ["Hello", "hello", "Hi"]

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the list

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check multiple values, use a list and `any()`

```
look_for = ["Hello", "hello", "Hi"]
txt = input(">> ")

if any(x in txt for x in look_for):
    print('found')
else:
    print('nope')
```

strings do not contain lists, so `list in str` will fail

Comment: Make sure you explain what is a List comprehension....

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you have missed quotations, all strings in python are enclosed in quotations. In your case python reads hello as a variable and won't find it.
try this

```
if "hello" in msg:
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
hello=["x", "y", "z"]
msg = input(">> ")
for h in hello:
  if h in msg:
    print(msg)
  else:
    print("not in msg")
```

**Requirements**

- you have a list of strings
- you want to check for each in a input string
- you may not know how to test or when to use a list
  comprehension

I use this basic code to check for keywords in data sets. its an easy way to test to see if I can find the data im looking for in files.

Comment: First of all, those are not python quotes. Next, ```hello``` and ```Hello``` are different. And the ```loop``` will keep printing ```msg``` everytime the condition is True

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
import re

hello = ["Hello", "hello", "Hi"]
msg = "Hi; this is my world"

for i in hello:
    if i in msg:
        #your condition
    else:
        continue # else statement will run 3 times since hello has three elements
```

Comment: You don't need to split the text. Looping over the list, then using `i in msg` will work fine for checking substrings

Comment: yes, I don't know why I made it complicated. Thank you